# How can I center the thumbnails in fancybox-3

Tags: thumbnails, fancybox-3

It looks like on older versions of fancybox there was a thumbnail helper that would center the thumbnails under the image.

Following the example here: https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/PdMvML
I can put the thumbnails along the bottom, but I'd like to center the thumbnails. Has anybody already figured out how to do this?

Here is the CSS to but the thumbnails on the bottom:

```
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .fancybox-thumbs {
    top: auto;
    width: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right : 0;
    height: 95px;
    padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }

  .fancybox-show-thumbs .fancybox-inner {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 95px;
  }
}
```

And here is the javascript to launch the thumbnails automatically.

```
$('[data-fancybox="images"]').fancybox({
  thumbs : {
    autoStart : true,
    axis      : 'x'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can center all the thumb images using this:

```
p.imglist {
text-align: center !important;
}

<p class="imglist"> </p>
```

Because the images are coming in the p tag with the class .imglist. Using this all the images will come in the center.